# Scraping and Handling 'application/amazonui-streaming-json' responses

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Noticed that Amazon uses 'application/amazonui-streaming-json' as a content type to some of their responses.

I've been trying to scrape some price information from their store, but it seems Scrapy can't seem to recognize the response in text format.

When I try:

```
price_request = Request(url, self.parse_price, 
                       headers= {'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'})
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'text'

Is there some way  I change the response type in a format I can parse through with Scrapy?

Comment: You could try somehow examine and change your `Response` in another callback like shown here - [Passing additional data to callback functions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions)

Comment: could you share your spider code? the `Response` object from scrapy doesn't contain an attribute `text` but `body`, looks like you are confusing it with the `requests` module.

Comment: Yes. You're right. Works like a charm and can be parsed if you use response.body

Comment: Since Scrapy 1.1, `response.text` gets you the body as unicode object (or str in Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was trying to parse the request using response.text. Using response.body did the trick.